# Can't figure out why the loop is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that there are countless questions about for loops or equivalent in JavaScript but I can't figure out how to make this one work.

```
<!-- Comes from https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js/edit/master/index.html -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/screenfull.js/5.0.2/screenfull.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <img id = "img1" src="https://placeimg.com/200/150/nature" alt="">  
        <img id = "img2" src="https://placeimg.com/200/150/nature/2" alt="">  
        <button id="test">Click</button>

        <script>
            
//      WORKS:
//      $(function () {
//          $('#img1').click(function () {
//              screenfull.request($('#img1')[0]);
//          });
//      });
            
        var ids = ["#img1", "#img2", "#test"];
        var item;
        for (item of ids) {
            $(function () {
                $(item).click(function()) {
                        screenfull.request($(item)[0]);
                }       
            })
        }
            
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Expected output: clicking on either of the two images should put it fullscreen.
Any idea? (I started with a for loop but I accept other solutions.)

I won't know the number of items in advance (nor their names) so the solution has to work with this specificity.

Comment: Why to use `document.ready` in a loop?

Comment: Where does it say that, @Teemu?

Comment: @LazarLjubenović `$(function () {...})` is a jQuery shortcut to `$(document).ready(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make a selector with both ids

```
$('#img1, #img2').click(function () {
  screenfull.request(this);
});
```

with an array

```
var imgs = ['#img1', '#img2'];
$(imgs.join(',')).click(function () {
  screenfull.request(this);
});
```

if you want to loop and reinvent what jQuery does for you

```
var imgs = ['#img1', '#img2'];
imgs.forEach(function(id){
  $(id).click(function () {
    screenfull.request(this);
  });
});
```

Comment: Okay but suppose I don't know in advance how many items I have in `ids`, how should I do that?

Comment: Use a common class or another selector. Hard to help more without knowing the exact details.

Comment: For some reasons, I can't do that, it has to be a list of ids. I'll modify the post accordingly

Comment: So if it is in an array join them.... `$(yourArray.join(","))`

Comment: could you include that in your answer? I don't know how to do that